# Fuzzy text matching in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of client provided data, a list of company names. I have to match those names with an internal database of company names.

The client list can fit in memory (its about 10k elements) but the interbal dataset is on hdfs and we use Spark for accesing it.

How could I go and match the client list? I was thinking in doing a matrix (RowMatrix) of N x D elements, n being the number of client elements and D being the length of the internal client list) and compute the similarities pair wise.

How could I do this in Spark? Any help would be more than welcome.

Comment: sounds a good starting point, have you tested it ?

Comment: Have you identified which fuzzy match alogorithm you have to use? You can try Spark Graph Mlib for your requirement.

Comment: I don't mind which similarity algorithm to use . We have Spark 1.3 installed at the moment so I dont think we can use Lehvenstein distance. I was thinking of using the stdlib difflib sequencematcher for similarity.

How would you do the fuzzy matching? I cant find any example or tutorial on the matter.